# How can I make a window update the ENTIRE background color in C using winapi

Tags: c++, c, windows, api

I am making a text editor in C using winapi and whenever I update the color with ChangeBKColor and ChangeTextColor it only changes one line and I have to press enter to fill out the rest.

How can I make it automatically update the entire window when the user pressed the button?
I have tried the RedrawWindow() and InvalidateRect functions but it only updates the first line

The relevant functions are WindowProcedure() and bkDialogProcedure()

Summary of the code, when the user clicks the menu button to change the background color, the changebackgroundcolor function is called

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//#Defines for menu events
#define FILEMENU_NEW 1
#define FILEMENU_OPEN 2
#define FILEMENU_SAVE 3
#define VIEWMENU_CHANGETEXTCOLOR 4
#define VIEWMENU_CHANGEBACKGROUNDCOLOR 5
#define exit_window 7
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK bkDialogProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM,LPARAM);

void AddMenus(HWND);
void AddControls(HWND);
void displayDialog(HWND);
void open_file_window(HWND);
void save_file(HWND);
void AddTextFont(HWND);
void changetextcolor(HWND);
void changebackgroundcolor(HWND);
void registerTextDialogClass(HINSTANCE);
void registerBkDialogClass(HINSTANCE);

HMENU hMenu;
HDC hdcEdit,hdcStatic;
HWND hPic,hMainWindow,hEdit,hBannerWindow;
HWND R,G,B, hPreview, hDlg; //Windows for the different color values corresponding to either R, G, or B
HWND sorry; //Window for the sorry message in the change colors dialog window  hopefully can get rid of it soon
HCURSOR hCursor;
HFONT textfont;

char char_text_red[4],char_text_green[4],char_text_blue[4],char_background_red[4],char_background_green[4],char_background_blue[4];
short int_text_RGB[3] = {255,255,255};  //Yes yes I know its not a int anymore, just to much work to change it all
short int_background_RGB[3] = {85,85,85};
short dialog_text_RGB[3];
short dialog_background_RGB[3];

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wp,LPARAM lp)
{
    int value;
    hdcEdit = (HDC)wp;
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:  //Cases for menu events in the main window
        switch (wp)
        {
        case FILEMENU_NEW:  //Event for new button being pressed

            break;
        case FILEMENU_OPEN:  //Events for open button being pressed
            open_file_window(hWnd);
            break;
        case FILEMENU_SAVE:
            save_file(hWnd);
            break;
        case VIEWMENU_CHANGETEXTCOLOR:
            changetextcolor(hWnd);
            break;
        case VIEWMENU_CHANGEBACKGROUNDCOLOR:
            changebackgroundcolor(hWnd);
            break;
    case WM_CREATE: //Case for when window is created
        AddMenus(hWnd); // all of these functions are needed to
        AddControls(hWnd); // create everything on startup
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY: //Case for when window is closed
        DeleteObject(textfont);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT: //Case for edit windows color
        SetTextColor(hdcEdit, RGB(int_text_RGB[0], int_text_RGB[1], int_text_RGB[2])); //Change text color to white
        SetBkColor(hdcEdit, RGB(int_background_RGB[0], int_background_RGB[1],            int_background_RGB[2]));
        return (LRESULT)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(int_background_RGB[0], int_background_RGB[1], int_background_RGB[2])); //Make entire edit window gray
        break;
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:  //Used to color the Banner window
        hdcStatic = (HDC)hBannerWindow;
        SetBkColor(hdcStatic,RGB(255,255,255));
        return (LRESULT)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(254,254,255));
        break; **
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd,msg,wp,lp);
    }
    return 1;
}

HWND mes;
HDC hdcPreview;

LRESULT CALLBACK bkDialogProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp,LPARAM lp)
{
    #define confirm 1
    #define preview 2
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        dialog_background_RGB[0] = int_background_RGB[0];
        dialog_background_RGB[1] = int_background_RGB[1];
        dialog_background_RGB[2] = int_background_RGB[2];
        dialog_text_RGB[0] = int_text_RGB[0];
        dialog_text_RGB[1] = int_text_RGB[1];
        dialog_text_RGB[2] = int_text_RGB[2];
        SendMessageW(hDlg, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)textfont, TRUE);
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE: //Events for dialog window closing
        EnableWindow(hMainWindow,1);
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND: //Events for button being pressed in the dialog window
        switch(wp)
        {
        case confirm:  //Events for the confirm button being pressed
            GetWindowText(R, char_background_red,4);
            GetWindowText(G, char_background_green,4);
            GetWindowText(B, char_background_blue,4);
            int_background_RGB[0] = atoi(char_background_red);
            int_background_RGB[1] = atoi(char_background_green);
            int_background_RGB[2] = atoi(char_background_blue);
            RedrawWindow(hEdit, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);
            EnableWindow(hMainWindow,1);
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        case preview:
            GetWindowText(R, char_background_red,4);
            GetWindowText(G, char_background_green,4);
            GetWindowText(B, char_background_blue,4);
            dialog_background_RGB[0] = atoi(char_background_red);
            dialog_background_RGB[1] = atoi(char_background_green);
            dialog_background_RGB[2] = atoi(char_background_blue);
            RedrawWindow(hPreview, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);
            SendMessage(hPreview,WM_CTLCOLOREDIT,0,0);
            break;
        }
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
        SetBkColor((HDC)wp,RGB(255,255,255));
        return (LRESULT)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));
        break;
    case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
        SetBkColor((HDC)wp,RGB(dialog_background_RGB[0],dialog_background_RGB[1],dialog_background_RGB[2]));
        SetTextColor((HDC)wp,RGB(dialog_text_RGB[0],dialog_text_RGB[1],dialog_text_RGB[2]));
        return (LRESULT)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(int_background_RGB[0],int_background_RGB[1],int_background_RGB[2]));
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd,msg,wp,lp);
    }
    return 1;
} **
void registerBkDialogClass(HINSTANCE hInst)  //Registers the dialog window
{
    WNDCLASSW bk_dialog = {0};

    bk_dialog.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));
    bk_dialog.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    bk_dialog.hInstance = hInst;
    bk_dialog.lpszClassName = L"myBkDialogClass";
    bk_dialog.lpfnWndProc = bkDialogProcedure;

    RegisterClassW(&bk_dialog);
}
void changebackgroundcolor(HWND hWnd)  //Displays the dialog window
{
    hDlg = CreateWindowW(L"myBkDialogClass",L"Change the background color",WS_OVERLAPPED|WS_VISIBLE|WS_MINIMIZEBOX|WS_SYSMENU,500,300,
                  600,500, hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    R = CreateWindowW(L"Edit",L"",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,280,230,45,20,hDlg,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    G = CreateWindowW(L"Edit",L"",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,330,230,45,20,hDlg,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    B = CreateWindowW(L"Edit",L"",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,380,230,45,20,hDlg,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"Confirm",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,200,445,100,20,hDlg,(HMENU)confirm,NULL,NULL); //Creates close button in dialog window
    sorry = CreateWindowW(L"Static",L"Sorry for the abomination please leave a suggestion for a better color",
                    WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD | ES_CENTER,170,300,400,37,hDlg,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    mes = CreateWindowW(L"Static",L"Enter the RGB code for the color you want",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD| SS_CENTER,200,205,350,20,hDlg,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"Preview Color",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,500,125,100,20,hDlg,(HMENU)preview,NULL,NULL);
    hPreview = CreateWindowW(L"Edit",L"This is the color of the background",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_MULTILINE | ES_WANTRETURN,0,0,300,200,hDlg,0,0,0);
    AddTextFont(hPreview);
    AddTextFont(R);
    AddTextFont(G);
    AddTextFont(B);
    AddTextFont(mes);
    AddTextFont(sorry);

    EnableWindow(hWnd,0); //Disables all but the dialog window when the dialog window is open
}
```

Comment: You are more likely to get helpful answers if you make your question as short as possible. It doesn't need to be an entire compilable program - just a few lines of code: "here's the function I call to clear the window, what am I doing wrong?"

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the non important parts